# How to index JSON web services into elasticsearch?

Tags: java, search, plugins, elasticsearch

Just started looking at elasticsearch, I understand the `curl` business to manually index JSON documents....

```
curl -XPUT 'http://myes:9200/users' -d '{ "name" : "foo" }'
```

..but I've got existing web services producing JSON, and I want to invoke those services and *pull* the JSON into ES programmatically using Java. I couldn't find a [plugin](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/plugins/) to do this, maybe I'm missing something, there's a damn plugin for everything else but not for simple JSON consumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're determined to *pull* the data from the ES side, you should look into Rivers:  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/river/

However, you could just as easily run a script (either on the server running ES or really anywhere for that matter) that fetches the JSON from your web services and pushes it into ES through a _bulk operation.

While rivers are super cool, there's more practicality in scripting your JSON into ES externally if you're new to ES and/or have a simple application.

Our team has used rivers in the past, but we've reverted to mostly relying on our own applications to push and pull data into ES (relying on _bulk insertions often).  There's just a lot more flexibility and little performance cost as opposed to rivers, especially using an externally hosted ElasticSearch like http://qbox.io.

Comment: That's pretty much what we did too, using a simple rest wrapper to pull data from our services, then pushing it to ES for indexing.